# What is the opposite of 202 Accepted?

Tags: http, http-response-codes

I'm a purist, therefore when my application encounters a problem whilst saving data, I like to return the correct http status codes to my users (other services).

It's easy when you can validate the request, or you know that your server died. But what happens when it's neither?

When all is good, and I can save the data, I return 202 Accepted.
What should I return when I couldn't save the data, but the data was indeed correct and my servers work perfectly and it's someone else's fault?

Specifically today I discovered a save issue when executing 2 related queries on a db cluster without sticky sessions.

I don't want to lie to my users. I want to say that "No, I couldn't save the data", but I don't want to blame it on them (4xx), and it's definitely not an internal server error.

Is there a "I couldn't do your bidding" or a "Something went wrong, try again" response?

Or am I just taking 500 too seriously and that should be the one I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is definitely a 500 error, keep in mind that every subsystem or service that you use under the hood is a part of your server from the client's point of view.

You can explain what happened in more detail in the response entity.

From [`rfc2616`](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt):

```
10.5 Server Error 5xx

   Response status codes beginning with the digit "5" indicate cases in
   which the server is aware that it has erred or is incapable of
   performing the request.
```

Comment: My problem is that the "server" (=service) is not incapable of performing the request it just encountered a hickup, you should be encouraged to try again. Most clients tend to treat 500s as death of the service, which is not the case.

Comment: 503 says 'temporarily' unavailable.

Comment: But that's not even true. It is available, you should retry immediately. 
I am inclined to accept 500/503, but it would be nice to find something that fits the purpose _exactly_.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for: 600 Retry :)

Or it could go into 5xx if must. 530? :)

Comment: I'm accepting this as there is no better solution currently, but I still feel there should be a blame-agnostic error code :)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the specific reason, but 503 Service Unavailable may be appropriate, and the fallback is a generic 500. Wikipedia has [a comprehensive list of status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).